# Kadena Pact Property Check

Tags: pact-lang, kadena

The Pact Language has a property system.
The call to `create-account` should fail for accounts shorter than 3 and longer than 256 chars. However, I couldn't make it work.

This is the result of REPL unit test.

I was expecting the `create-account` call with a name shorter than 3 chars to fail.

```
"FAILURE: empty account names fail to create: expected failure, got result = "Write succeeded""
"FAILURE: account names not >= 3 chars fail: expected failure, got result = "Write succeeded""
"FAILURE: account names not <= 256 chars fail: expected failure, got result = "Write succeeded""
```

create-account function with validate-id

```
  (defun create-account:string
    ( account:string
      guard:guard )

    @doc " Create a new account. "

    @model [ (property (valid-account-id account)) ]
    (enforce-reserved account guard)

    (insert token-table account
      { "balance" : 0.0
      , "guard"   : guard
      }
    )
  )
```

This is the model definition

```
(module k-token GOVERNANCE

  @doc "K token smart contract"

  @model
    [ (defproperty conserves-mass (amount:decimal)
        (= (column-delta token-table 'balance) 0.0))

      (defproperty valid-account-id (accountId:string)
        (and
          (>= (length accountId) 3)
          (<= (length accountId) 256)))
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Properties and models are not used on-chain... They are just only for formal verification.

Your `create-account` should call a function to verify the account string. You can look at the coin module and its function (validate-account)as an example.

Kudos to `Pascal3125` on Kadena discord channel.